# Are review stats from web API outdated?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I'm trying to get summary info about user reviews with web API (for example, for "The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim"):
https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/72850?json=1&language=all

I get following data:

```
"total_positive":145480,"total_negative":9413,"total_reviews":154893
```

But when I'm looking into reviews in the Skyrim page, I see these numbers:

[image: "Customer reviews" information from store.steampowered.com]

Why I get different values with API and web-site? Am I doing something wrong? Or API is outdated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha, `purchase_type=all` did the trick. I'm just careless.